# Is it possible to do a wget dry-run?

Tags: wget

I know you can download webpages recursively using `wget`, but is it possible to do a dry-run? So that you could sort of do a test-run to see how much would be downloaded if you actually did it? Thinking about pages that have a lot of links to media files like for example images, audio or movie files.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `--spider` switch.

Comment: Don't forget the `-nd` (don't create directories) flag if you use it with the `-r` (recursive) flag.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use `-R` to reject media files until you're ready to actually download them.

Comment: Would you get any indication on how much you rejected?

Answer (score 0):

Using `--spider` as noted in [paradroid's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1516712/300293) is great for most cases, but if you're trying to get the filename it would create (e.g. thanks to `--restrict-file-names` or just to reliably translate the uri's encoding), the resulting "Remote file exists" output is insufficient.

My solution was to ensure it can't write the file and then capture the error:

```
filename="$(wget -P /. "$uri" 2>&1 \
  |awk 'pd = index($0, ": Permission denied") {print substr($0, 4, pd - 4)}'
)"
echo "Would save: $filename"
```

The `-P /.` option specifies a directory prefix of `/`, root. (Oddly, `wget` ignores `-P /` and writes to the local directory instead. The dot works around that.)

Note that you should not run this as a user with write access to `/`. If you have such access, try this instead:

```
filename="$(
  d="$(mktemp -d)";
  chmod 000 $d;
  wget -P $d "$uri" 2>&1 |awk -v d=$d/ '
    a = index($0, d) && b = index($0, ": Permission denied") {
      a += length(d);
      print substr($0, a, b - a)
    }
  ';
  rm -rf $d
)"
echo "Would save: $filename"
```

This makes a temporary directory, renders it unwritable, then runs `wget` with it as the prefix. It then removes the temporary directory.